# Can we make hidden routes with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to know if it's possible to make some hidden routes with angularjs, for example I have a category and sub category, in my application I have

```
.when('/category/new' ,{ 
    controller : 'newCategoryCtrl', 
    templateUrl : '/category.html'
    })
.when('/category/:id/sub/new' ,
         { controller : 'newSubCategoryCtrl', 
    templateUrl : '/subCategory.html'
    })....
```

in my case , if you want to add new subcategories you have to search by category, and after that you have the access to subcategory view. but the problem with configuration, you can access this url if you know it without any restriction

Comment: Why do you restrict the user `not` to enter sub category? if he knows the category id, he can directly enter it by the url.

Comment: yes, it's a one case, but it still possible he will make a mistake, but there is othercase where we want to restrict access to some views, for example I have using ionize Cms  [link](http://ionizecms.com/en/support/userguide/quickstart/put-one-element-online-offline) for past time and we can make some offline views. so I think it's the same functionality

Comment: You have to restrict access on the server side. Otherwise a user will **always** be able to access the view.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a route that will handle the incorrect sub-route before the correct sub-route. You can actually leverage the same sub-route controller, evaluate the `$routeParams` and bounce back to whatever route you like.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/page/new', { templateUrl: 'page.html', controller: 'pageCtrl'})
        .when('/page/:id/:substuff', {templateUrl: 'subPage.html', controller: 'subPageCtrl'})
        .when('/page/:id/sub/new', {templateUrl: 'subPage.html', controller: 'subPageCtrl'})
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/page/new' });
}]);
```

[Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4KdvioBnRCWy9lz8u1xY?p=preview)

Comment: yes, but this not our case, what I want that nobody could access the route page/: id/sub/new directly from the navigation bar of the browser. I think the only possible solution that when resolving the view we make calls to the server side for validating the page id like he has mentioned zeroflagL .Thank you for your answer

Comment: The only choices in that situation are 1) don't specify default route on `$routeProvider`, 2) handle the restricted route and redirect to some desired route, 3) allow redirect to default route when restricted route is accessed.